# How to find MacOS 'Utilities' folder contents with Python

Tags: python, macos, pathlib

When calling :

```
 Path('/Applications/Utilities').iterdir()
```

The returned result is only '.localized' but when I look in the Utilities folder with finder there are many apps - Disk Utility, Airport Utility, etc.

I hav also tried .listdir() with the OS module and same result.

Bigger code sample

```
def find_apps(directory_item: Path, nested_apps: list) -> None:

if item_is_app(directory_item):
    nested_apps.append(directory_item)
    return

if item_is_directory(directory_item):
    for item in directory_item.iterdir():
        find_apps(item, nested_apps)

return
```

I can't seem to figure out how to view the apps in the Utilities directory - I don't have a problem with other folders in the directory. e.g. My Python 3.11 folder correctly produces all apps such as Python Launcher.app and IDLE.app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now the Applications from an OS installation are located in the `/System/Applications/` folder. So in your case `/System/Applications/Utilities/`.

Comment: Note that user-installed utilities *will* be in `/Applications/Utilities/`, so you may need to iterate over both to get the full list of available utilities.

Comment: In my case I can go straight to ```System/Applications/Utilities/``` to get all installed applications. Are you aware of when applications installed by user are placed in ```System/App...``` vs ```App.../```?

Comment: It's a security concern, only apps comming with a fresh install by Apple are placed in /System/Applications